# Fixed pricing per product until X qty then free but for various products

Tags: shipping, ce-1.8.1.0

I'm on Magento ver. 1.8.1.0 and I'm in a unique situation... My website is: http://tinyurl.com/k8ch6xj

The client originally had one product but in various colors, the product cost $39.95 each and after they order 2 or more products, the entire order ships free. In Magento I have it set to where anything over $70.89 ships free. Anything below $70.89 will ship using the UPS module with special UPS rates they have from UPS.

Now they have two types of products called insoles, one cost $8.95 and the other is $19.95. They want the insoles to be shipped for $3.95 each and if a customer orders over 3 insoles, shipping is free.

How can I make it so Magento recognizes this? Where each insole costs $3.95 to ship, after 3 it ships free, then if they order 1 pair of shoes they will still be charged for UPS shipping for that one pair, but if they order 2 pair everything ships free even if they order 1 pair of insoles.

Answer (score 1):

Create 2 rules under admin - promotions - shopping cart rules with "free shipping action" and remove free shipping as a carrier.